# How to write a wrapper enum for C error codes?

Tags: rust, error-handling

I am writing a Rust wrapper for a C API. It contains a function that may fail, in which case it returns an error code encoded as an `int`. Let's call these `SOME_ERROR` and `OTHER_ERROR`, and they will have the values 1 and 2, respectively. I want to write an enum wrapping these error codes, as follows:

```rust
// Declared in a seperate C header
const SOME_ERROR: c_int = 1;
const OTHER_ERROR: c_int = 2;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
#[repr(i32)]
enum ErrorCodeWrapper {
    SomeError = SOME_ERROR,
    OtherError = OTHER_ERROR,
}
```

Here comes my first question. It does not seem to be possible to specify `std::os::raw::c_int` as the underlying type of an enum. But I do feel like it should be, as `int` isn't required to be 32 bits wide. Is there any way to achieve this?

I'd then like some methods to convert to and from a raw error code:

```rust
use std::os::raw::c_int;

impl ErrorCodeWrapper {
    fn from_raw(raw: c_int) -> Option<Self> {
        match raw {
            SOME_ERROR => Some(Self::SomeError),
            OTHER_ERROR => Some(Self::OtherError),
            _ => None
        }
    }

    unsafe fn from_raw_unchecked(raw: c_int) -> Self {
        *(&raw as *const _ as *const Self)
    }

    fn as_raw(self) -> c_int {
        unsafe { *(&self as *const _ as *const c_int) }
    }
}
```

The only way I could find to "bit-cast" `c_int` to and from `ErrorCodeWrapper` is to do it C-style, by casting a pointer and then dereferencing it. This should work as `ErrorCodeWrapper` and `int` have the same size and alignment, and the value of every `ErrorCodeWrapper` variant maps to its corresponding error code. However, this solution is a bit to hackery for my taste; is there a more idiomatic one, like C++'s [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast)?

Furthermore, is it possible to replace the `match` statement in `ErrorCodeWrapper::from_raw` with a simple validity check, for simpler code in the case of more variants?

The last bit of code, the necessary error implementations:

```rust
use std::{fmt::Display, error::Error};

impl Display for ErrorCodeWrapper {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", match self {
            Self::SomeError => "some error",
            Self::OtherError => "some other error",
        })
    }
}

impl Error for ErrorCodeWrapper {}
```

Now let's imagine a second wrapper, `SuperErrorCodeWrapper`, that includes some or all of the variants of `ErrorCodeWrapper`, with the same description and everything. That would mean that either:

- One could "factor out" the common variants of `ErrorCodeWrapper` and `SuperErrorCodeWrapper` into a separate enum. `ErrorCodeWrapper` and `SuperErrorCodeWrapper` would then have a variant containing this enum. However I am not really fond of this kind of nesting, which would seem arbitrary when focusing on one particular error.
- Duplicating the common variants across both enums.

The latter would add a lot to the existing boilerplate. Could a macro be a viable option to handle this?

*Is there a library that could handle all this for me?*

Comment: Notice that the `from_raw_unchecked` function constitutes undefined behavior. While it may seem to work by accident, it *will* break.

Comment: How is it UB? Assuming `c_int` is equivalent to `i32`, it has the same size and alignment as `ErrorCode`, so shouldn't `from_raw_unchecked` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here comes my first question. It does not seem to be possible to specify `std::os::raw::c_int` as the underlying type of an enum. But I do feel like it should be, as `int` isn't required to be 32 bits wide. Is there any way to achieve this?

No. [There was an RFC in 2016](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1605) (I can't even access the RFC text. it seems it was removed), but it was closed:

> We discussed in the @rust-lang/lang meeting and decided that while the RFC is well-motivated, it doesn't sufficiently address the various implementation complexities that must be overcome nor the interaction with hygiene. It would make sense to extend the attribute system to support more general paths before considering this RFC (but that is a non-trivial undertaking).

The best you can do is to use `#[cfg_attr]` with all configurations. [`c_int` is defined here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.62.0/src/core/ffi/mod.rs.html#158-172) as, and all current options are

```
#[cfg_attr(any(target_arch = "avr", target_arch = "msp430"), repr(i16))]
#[cfg_attr(not(any(target_arch = "avr", target_arch = "msp430")), repr(i32))]
enum ErrorCodeWrapper { ... }
```

> is there a more idiomatic one, like C++'s [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast)?

Yes; [`std::mem::transmute()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html).

> One could "factor out" the common variants of `ErrorCodeWrapper` and `SuperErrorCodeWrapper` into a separate enum. `ErrorCodeWrapper` and `SuperErrorCodeWrapper` would then have a variant containing this enum.

If you do that, you lose the ability to `transmute()` (or pointer cast, it doesn't matter), as they'll be no longer layout compatible with `int`.

> Could a macro be a viable option to handle this?

Probably yes.

> Is there a library that could handle all this for me?

I don't know all library that handles all of this (although it is possible that one exists), but there is [`thiserror`](https://docs.rs/thiserror) (and friends) for the `Error` and `Display` implementations, and [`strum::FromRepr`](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/derive.FromRepr.html) that can help you with `from_raw()`.